# CloudantDB & NodeJS: Query data with specific id

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I just created a NodeJS cloudantDB web starter on bluemix. Then, I have a API get data from cloudantDB and get successfull but it returns all data. Please see js file:

js file:

```
app.get('/api/provider', function(request, response) {

    console.log("Get method invoked.. ")

    db = cloudant.use(dbCredentials.dbProvider);
    var docList = [];
    var i = 0;
    db.list(function(err, body) {
        if (!err) {
            var len = body.rows.length;
            console.log('total # of docs -> '+len);
            if(len == 0) {
                // error
            } else {
                body.rows.forEach(function(document) {
                    db.get(document.id, { revs_info: true }, function(err, doc) {
                        if (!err) {
                            if(doc['_attachments']) {
                                // todo
                            } else {
                                var responseData = createResponseDataProvider(
                                        doc._id,
                                        doc.provider_type,
                                        doc.name,
                                        doc.phone,
                                        doc.mobile,
                                        doc.email,
                                        doc.logo,
                                        doc.address
                                        );
                            }
                            docList.push(responseData);
                            i++;
                            if(i >= len) {
                                response.write(JSON.stringify(docList));
                                console.log('ending response...');
                                response.end();
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });

                });
            }

        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

If I want to add parameter to API to get specific data from DB , Do we need create search index or query on cloudant, afer that call API the same : `app.get('/api/provider/:id')`. Please help me review and sharing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a search function of Cloudant.

1. You need to create search index. In search index you can manage what data you want to get.
    Example: https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/
2. Following this code after create search index.

...

```
var query = {q: "id:doc.id"};
db.search('design document name', 'index name', query, function(er, result) {
   if (er) {
      throw er;
   }
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: after query, I want to add parameter q:'id:'+request.params.id+"&include_docs=true". Does it work well?

Comment: no, you can't use "&include_docs=true" like a parameter in cloudant. Please read the doucment it have a list of parameter which you can use for query your data

Answer (score 1):

you could get the document by id/name:

```
db.get(docID, function(err, data) {
  // do something
});
```

references:
  https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#document-functions
  https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#api-reference